# RestEASY and Jackson incompatibility - NoSuchMethodException

Tags: java, jackson, jboss7.x, resteasy, wildfly

I migrated my project from **JBoss AS 7.2** to **WildFly 8.0** and after some time of updating versions I can't figure out, how to solve *RestEASY* and *Jackson* incompatibility.

In **JBoss AS 7.2** I used *RestEASY 3.0.6.Final* and *Jackson 2.2.1* and they worked like a charm. But now, with **WildFly's** *Jackson 2.3*, there is an incompatibility. Server throws an NoSuchMethodError exception:

```
13:56:27,049 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-3) UT005023: Exception handling request to /iqpp/applicants/: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.jackson.ResteasyJackson2Provider._configForWriting(Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper;[Ljava/lang/annotation/Annotation;)Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/jaxrs/json/JsonEndpointConfig;
at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.jackson.ResteasyJackson2Provider.writeTo(ResteasyJackson2Provider.java:137) [resteasy-jackson2-provider-3.0.6.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.AbstractWriterInterceptorContext.writeTo(AbstractWriterInterceptorContext.java:129) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.6.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.ServerWriterInterceptorContext.writeTo(ServerWriterInterceptorContext.java:62) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.6.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.AbstractWriterInterceptorContext.proceed(AbstractWriterInterceptorContext.java:118) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.6.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.resteasy.security.doseta.DigitalSigningInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(DigitalSigningInterceptor.java:143) [resteasy-crypto-3.0.6.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.AbstractWriterInterceptorContext.proceed(AbstractWriterInterceptorContext.java:122) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.6.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.interceptors.encoding.GZIPEncodingInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(GZIPEncodingInterceptor.java:100) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.6.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.AbstractWriterInterceptorContext.proceed(AbstractWriterInterceptorContext.java:122) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.6.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ServerResponseWriter.writeNomapResponse(ServerResponseWriter.java:99) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.6.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.writeResponse(SynchronousDispatcher.java:427) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.6.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:376) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.6.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invokePropagateNotFound(SynchronousDispatcher.java:217) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.6.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:224) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.6.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.FilterDispatcher.doFilter(FilterDispatcher.java:62) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.6.Final.jar:]
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:56) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
at org.apache.deltaspike.servlet.impl.event.EventBridgeFilter.doFilter(EventBridgeFilter.java:59) [deltaspike-servlet-module-impl-0.5.jar:0.5]
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:56) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
at org.apache.deltaspike.servlet.impl.produce.RequestResponseHolderFilter.doFilter(RequestResponseHolderFilter.java:50) [deltaspike-servlet-module-impl-0.5.jar:0.5]
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:56) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:85) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:61) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:113) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationCallHandler.java:52) [undertow-core-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:45) [undertow-core-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:61) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:70) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76) [undertow-core-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:240) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:227) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:73) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:146) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:168) [undertow-core-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:687) [undertow-core-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
```

All my colleagues get the same error. Can you tell me what version should I use?

**UPDATE:**

*ResteasyJackson2Provider* class from jar **resteasy-jackson2-provider** extends *JacksonJaxbJsonProvider* from jar **jackson-jaxrs-json-provider** and calls method

```
  protected JsonEndpointConfig _configForWriting(ObjectMapper mapper, Annotation[] annotations)
```

in **jackson-jaxrs-json-provider-2.2.1** it is OK, but in **jackson-jaxrs-json-provider-2.3.0** this method has different arguments:

```
  protected JsonEndpointConfig _configForWriting(ObjectWriter writer, Annotation[] annotations)
```

I think this is an official bug.

Comment: The joke is that this stacktrace is NOT complaining about a method of Jackson not existing, it is complaining about a method in the resteasy package space not existing. It looks like there is a compatibility issue between resteasy and a resteasy jackson provider jar.

Comment: actually i think that problem is not in the provider but in the jackson itself

Comment: You have to back up what you say. At least I point to proof, you just make a wild claim and make the world assume that you are always right.

Comment: I found it, see update

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to comments under this [commit](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-jaxrs-providers/commit/bafb6fb64bc15482c7bfc56784169204d6c4b1f2) to **jackson-jaxrs-providers** 
the breakage was not intentional and will be resolved in jackson-jaxrs-providers patch version 2.3.2.

Comment: any idea when 2.3.2 will be out?

Comment: so I replaced jackson-jaxrs-json-provider, jackson-jaxrs-base, jackson-module-jaxb-annotations with version 2.3.2, but I still get the same NoSuchMethodException. How do I work around this bug?

Comment: The problem is, AIUI, they put the methods back, but they're not binary compatible. RESTEasy would have to be compiled against 2.3.2. In WildFly upstream a downgrade to 2.2.3 was done, https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY-2959

Comment: I can confirm that the nightly build does indeed fix this https://community.jboss.org/thread/224262 as of Apr 1, 2014

Answer (score -1):

Try to run it in wildfly-8.2.0.Final.