# Unable to use jackson in wildfly9

Tags: java, json, jackson, wildfly

Running in Wildfly9, my application makes a rest call to another server.
I get the error messsage

```
javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: Unable to invoke request
at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.engines.AppacheHttpClient4Engine.invoke(AppacheHttpClient4Engine.java:287)
...
Caused by: javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: could not find writer for content-type application/json: type java.lang.String
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.ClientWriterInterceptorContext.throwWriterNotFoundException(ClientWriterInterceptorContext.java:40)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.AbstractWriterInterceptorContext.getWriter(AbstractWriterInterceptorContext.java:138)
```

If I run my code 'standalone' (not in Wildfly), the rest call works. The error is probably caused by a misconfiguration by me (and I'm a newbie when it comes to Wildfly).

Most posts that i've seen has been about Wildfly8, e.g. 
https://developer.jboss.org/thread/237728?_sscc=t
 and [RestEASY and Jackson incompatibility - NoSuchMethodException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21780208/resteasy-and-jackson-incompatibility-nosuchmethodexception), none about Wildfly9 :(

I've modified the META-INF/jboss-deployment-structure.xml to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure>
  <deployment>
    <exclusions>
      <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jackson-provider"/>
      <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jettison-provider"/>
    </exclusions>
    <dependencies>
      <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jackson2-provider" services="import" />
    </dependencies>
  </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Is this neccessary? From posts, I get the impression jackson2 is default in Wildfly9.

My jackson dependencies in the pom file are:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

I've also tried with version 2.3.2 of the jackson jars as well as adding

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-base</artifactId>
  <version>2.3.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
  <version>2.3.2</version>
</dependency>
```

In the wildfly configuration, I use the standalone-full.xml configuration file (renamed to standalone.xml).
Do I need to add an extension for jackson2 too?

I appreciate any help/link that points me into the right direction.